# shortcut calling cmd and use user input for command e.g. ping

Tags: batch-file, cmd, user-input, var, expansion

I try to call cmd in a shortcut and use set /p user input to execute ping with it, but i don't get the var resolved. i tried from simple to enhanced but no good:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k set /p XYZ=IP? && ping %XYZ%

%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set /p XYZ=IP? && ping %XYZ%

%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set /p XYZ=IP? && ping %~XYZ%

%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set /p XYZ=IP? && ping %%XYZ%
```

what do i miss please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p XYZ=IP? && call ping %XYZ%
```

Comment: sometimes it is so simple, while hard to see trees in a forrest, thank you endoro

Answer (score 1):

When using the `set` command in one line, through the use of `&`, the variable won't be set till the end of the line. To demonstrate this, run this as a batch file

#### Input:

```
set var=FALSE
set var=TRUE & Echo var state: %var%
Echo var state: %var%
Echo ----------------------------------------
set var=
set /p "var=: " & if not defined var Echo The variable var has no value
if defined var Echo The variable var is: %var%
```

#### Output:

```
var state: FALSE
var state: TRUE
----------------------------------------
The variable var has no value
The variable var is: test
```

As you can see, you can only accces the previous values of a variable in a line of code. The best thing you could do is:

#### C:\pingr.bat

```
setlocal 
set var=%~1
if "%1"=="" "var=Ip: "
set /p target="%var%"
ping %target%
Endlocal
```

Then in your cmd, shortcut simply type:

```
cmd /c "call C:\pingr.bat Ip?"
```

And your problem should be solved.

Mona

Comment: Thanks for your efforts mona - exactly this behaviour was what i did experience, but i don't wont to use a bat file to keep it more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `!XYZ!` if you want delayed expansion, and SETLOCAL only works within a batch context, not from the command line. You must use the CMD.EXE `/V:ON` option to enable delayed expansion for the command line. Also, the command string must be quoted, or the `&&` must be escaped, in order to have PING execute after the SET command instead of after the CMD.EXE command.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /v:on /k "set /p XYZ=IP? && ping !XYZ!"
```

Comment: interesting, while ping is not executed in my cmd with this line. it just ends after getting the Input?

Comment: @peet - Oops, I didn't bother to test. Of course it failed - the `&&` needed to be quoted or escaped. See updated answer.

Comment: weird, the need to escape seems to be an impact of the /v switch not of &&. thank you for your input - while i guess the call method is the smartest way to handle syntax and readability.

Comment: @peet - In my hands on Win7 I must quote or escape even without the /v option. I should think it would be the same in other Windows versions, but I can't test at the moment.

Comment: you arr right i did mix up with - guess what - take the string and put it in a shortcut and it will work?! :) `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k set /p XYZ=IP? && call ping %XYZ%`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I tested it and works like a charm. In the output file you´ll get time, date and the ICMP test information.

---

```
 @echo Type an IP address. At the end press ctrl+c and choose N
 @echo off

 setlocal

 set var=%~1
 if "%1" ==" "var=Ip: "
 set /p target="%var%"

 for /F "delims=" %%i in ('ping %target% -t') do call :format "%%i"
 goto :done

 :format
 echo %date% %time% %1 1>> output.txt

 :done
```